# FilterRegistrationBean url pattern doesn't work

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-security

I am registering a filter as shown below For log output

i want url pattern : `/*/api/*`

```
@Bean
public CommonsRequestLoggingFilter commonsRequestLoggingFilter() {
    CommonsRequestLoggingFilter filter = new CommonsRequestLoggingFilter();
    filter.setIncludeClientInfo(true);
    filter.setIncludeHeaders(true);
    filter.setIncludePayload(true);
    filter.setIncludeQueryString(true);
    filter.setMaxPayloadLength(1000);
    return filter;
}


     @Bean
    public FilterRegistrationBean filterRegistrationBean () {
        final FilterRegistrationBean registrationBean = new FilterRegistrationBean();
        registrationBean.addUrlPatterns("/*/api/*");

        return registrationBean;
    }
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Since the code registers a Servlet `Filter`, the URL pattern must conform to the URL mappings supported by Servlets/Filters, as specified in the Servlet Specification:

> **12.2 Specification of Mappings**
>
> In the Web application deployment descriptor, the following syntax is used to define mappings:
>
> - A string beginning with a `/` character and ending with a `/*` suffix is used for path mapping.
> - A string beginning with a `*.` prefix is used as an extension mapping.
> - The empty string ("") is a special URL pattern that exactly maps to the application's context root, i.e., requests of the form `http://host:port/<context-root>/`. In this case the path info is `/` and the servlet path and context path is empty string (““).
> - A string containing only the `/` character indicates the "default" servlet of the application. In this case the servlet path is the request URI minus the context path and the path info is null.
> - All other strings are used for exact matches only.

So, a URL can have only one wildcard, and it must be first or last:

- `/some/path/*`
- `*.ext`